# Firefly "Reaver Cutter" nav card

Tags: firefly

Situation: Player1 moves into a sector containing a ship of Player2 and draws "Reaver Cutter" nav card (which means moving Reavers into the same sector and applying Reaver Contact effects immediately). Do Reavers attack both ships or only the Player1? I.E. does Player2 have the contact immediately or only on the start of his turn? There is a difference because Reavers may leave the sector before the turn of the Player2 begins.

Comment: @ikegami probably not, similar situation is described in the FAQ_v3 regarding Alliance Cruiser. It's said that Contact is resolved once per encounter, quite reasonably.

Comment: I'd say yes, and apply that rule to the reavers too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Reaver Cutter is resolved upon the players turn start. The Alliance Cruiser is resolved immediately. This is to simulate the Reavers "not being hungry" and the Alliance Cruiser "getting awfully crowded in my sky..."